# How to create a pull-request in github from the command line

Tags: git, github

Suppose I make some changes to files, and commit and push the changes to a new branch which I push to github, i.e. something like this:

```
git commit -m "some changes"
git checkout -b testbranch
git push --set-upstream origin testbranch
```

Now I want to create a pull request from the command line. I tried

```
git request-pull testbranch git@github.com:alex4200/hello-world.git
```

but this says

```
warn: No match for commit a7c79dc732b3f00d6cf6ffe98e6c79de87110b7b found at git@github.com:alex4200/hello-world.git
warn: Are you sure you pushed 'HEAD' there?
```

But I see that commit on the github under the given branch with the given commit hash.

What do I misunderstand now?

Comment: Use the [PR API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls)

Comment: @Liam I will try if it is not possible otherwise. But why does a command like `request-pull` exists in the first place then?

Comment: Worth noting that PRs are not a GIT thing. It's a workflow thing. GIT is source control not workflow

Comment: Because GIT has no concept of a PR. This is something in Github. A Pr is just a merge as far as GIT is concerned

Comment: @Liam Thanks for the info, however it does not work. I get the `message:Not found`. I guess I have yet to create another SO question...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+pull+request+command+line

Comment: https://cli.github.com/ , https://hub.github.com/

Answer (score 4):

> What do I misunderstand now?

You have confused Git request pull with GitHub pull request.

Git request pull is literally a message to a friend *requesting* them to *pull* from you. It has nothing to do with GitHub.

You are looking for the `hub` tool:

https://hub.github.com/hub-pull-request.1.html

For installation instructions see

https://github.com/github/hub